# MongoDB : OrderBy a specific field in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have document structure like that :

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4ed3733abde68a21780000a0"),
  [HERE OTHER DATA...]
  "myArray": [
    {
      "name": "myName1",
      "value": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "myName2",
      "value": "myValue"
    },
    {
      "name": "myName3",
      "value": 14.6
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to do a query documents ordered by a specific field in the array "myArray".

Example : I want to query documents ordered by myArray[name="myName1"].value

If myArray[name="myName1"] doesn't exist, it must be at the end of the result list.

If myArray[name="myName1"] exist two times in the document, maybe take the first.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can possibly order by array "index" normally with sort:

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "myArray.0.value": 1 })
```

But if you really wanted to sort by a matching "name", then you would need to do this instead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "field": 1,
       "anotherField": 1,
       "myArray": 1,
       "sortField": { 
           "$setDifference": [
               { "$map": {
                   "input": "$myArray",
                   "as": "el",
                   "in": {
                       "$cond": [
                           { "$eq": [ "$$el.name", "myName1" ] },
                           "$$el.value",
                           false
                       ]
                   }
               }},
               [false]
           ]
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "sortField": 1 } }
])
```

Which essentially "filters out" the field value you want to use where it matches and then allows that new projected field ( still actually an array, though a single element, or maybe none ) to be used to sort on.

Also see [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [other aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for their usage.

Note that if your "name" to be matched on does not exist in the array, then the results might not be what you want.

But you cannot "just provide the name" to match directly to `.sort()` since it just does not work that way. Hence the longer construct to make it happen.